# How to extract certain items from list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x

Suppose I have these lists:

```
a = ['2009','2010a','2010b','2011','2012a','2012b','2012c','2013a','2014b'] 
b = ['2008a','2008b']
```

and I need to write a code that give me the following lists:

```
#If I provide list a as the input:
a1 = ['2010a','2010b']
a2 = ['2012a','2012b','2012c']
a3 = ['2013a']
a4 = ['2014b']

#If I provide list b as the input:
b1 = ['2008a','2008b']
```

Currently, I do the followings:

1. Iterate over every item in the input list
2. Check if the last string of each item is alphabet `(e.g. a of '2010a')`
3. Check if the last string of the next item is also alphabet `(e.g. '2010a' and '2010b')`
4. Keep checking until the last string of the next item is not alphabet`(e.g. '2010a','2010b','2011')` and collect the previous items that end with alphabets `(e.g. '2010a' and '2010b')`
5. Check if the collected items have the same digits `(e.g. '2010a' and '2010b', but not '2013a' and '2014b')` and produce the sub-lists as appropriate.

The above steps work, but are quite long. I wonder if there is any code/trick in python libraries that can make the code shorter and look cleaner/ more elegant.

Comment: Once you have segregated the items that end with an _alphabet_ character, [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can organize those items by the first 4 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to check if the last character is a letter:

```
>>> a = ['2009','2010a','2010b','2011','2012a','2012b','2012c','2013a','2014b']
>>> number_and_letters = [x for x in a if x[-1].isalpha()]
['2010a', '2010b', '2012a', '2012b', '2012c', '2013a', '2014b']
```

You can then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a `lambda` of `x[:4]` to group the strings by numbers:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(list(words) for year, words in itertools.groupby(number_and_letters, lambda x: x[:4]))
[['2010a', '2010b'], ['2012a', '2012b', '2012c'], ['2013a'], ['2014b']]
```

`groupby` expects strings to be already sorted, which seems to be the case here.

Finally, you get a list as an output, not 4 distinct variables. It's usually much easier to work with a list of 4 elements than with 4 distinct variables.

Comment: I modify it slightly to fit my other codes: `comp_dict = {key:[item for item in group] for key,group in groupby(number_and_letters, lambda x: x[:-1])}`